# WSO2 API Manager Gateway cluster is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I configure the gateway cluster follow this guide:https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Clustering+the+Gateway.

172.19.28.71: Gateway Manager Host
172.19.28.84: Gateway Worker Host

Gateway Manager axis2.xml:

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
        <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
        <parameter name="domain">wso2.am.internal.domain</parameter>
        <parameter name="localMemberHost">172.19.28.71</parameter>
        <parameter name="localMemberPort">4500</parameter>
        <members>
            <member>
                  <hostName>172.19.28.71</hostName>
                  <port>4500</port>
            </member>
            <member>
                  <hostName>172.19.28.84</hostName>
                  <port>4200</port>
            </member>
        </members>
```

Gateway Worker axis2.xml:

```
<clustering class="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastClusteringAgent"
                enable="true">
    <parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
    <parameter name="domain">wso2.am.internal.domain</parameter>
    <parameter name="localMemberHost">172.19.28.84</parameter>
    <parameter name="localMemberPort">4200</parameter>
    <members>
        <member>
              <hostName>172.19.28.71</hostName>
              <port>4500</port>
        </member>
        <member>
              <hostName>172.19.28.84</hostName>
              <port>4200</port>
        </member>
    </members>
```

Publiser and Store api-manager.xml:

```
    <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
        <Name>Internal</Name>
        <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
        <ServerURL>https://172.19.28.71:9443/services/</ServerURL> 
        <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
        <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
 <GatewayEndpoint>http://172.19.28.84:8280,https://172.19.28.84:8243</GatewayEndpoint>
    </Environment>
```

***But When I test in API Console(Gateway Worker URL:https://172.19.28.84:8243/pizzashack/3.0.0), nothing response, following is Gateway Worker's log:***

```
[2017-05-16 10:15:57,996]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  STATUS = Message dispatched to the main sequence. Invalid URL., RESOURCE = /pizzashack/3.0.0/menu {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

***Gateway Manager URL (172.19.28.71:8243/pizzashack/3.0.0) is working.***

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [SVN based deployment synchronizer](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+SVN-Based+Deployment+Synchronizer) between gateways. Otherwise, pizzashack API won't be deployed in all the gateways.